# difference between getx and getminx

Tags: java

I have a question about Java's Rectangle class. I'm wondering what's the difference between 
`rectangle.getX()` and `rectangle.getMinX()`. 
When I google searched that, in the Java Documentation I read this for `getX()`:

Returns the X coordinate of the bounding Rectangle in double precision.

For `getMinX()` I've read the following:

Returns the smallest X coordinate of the framing rectangle of the Shape in double precision.

Now I am wondering: How can there be different X coordinates if for a Rectangle, there should be only one:

```
new Rectangle(0,0,100,100) = p1(0,0)|p2(100,0)|p3(0,100)|p4(100,100).
```

I'd understand if e.g. `getMaxX()` would be something like `getX()+getWidth()`, but then what would `getMinX()` be?
I'm very confused about this.

I just need a short explanation, I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A rectangle is defined by: (x<sub>1</sub>,y<sub>1</sub>),(x<sub>2</sub>,y<sub>2</sub>).  For our purposes, let us denote (x<sub>1</sub>,y<sub>1</sub>) and the *upper-left-corner* of the the rectangle and (x<sub>2</sub>,y<sub>2</sub>) as the *bottom-right-corner*.

`rectangle.getX()` returns x<sub>1</sub>, whereas `rectangle.getMinX()` returns x<sub>k</sub> such that: for all x<sub>i</sub> in X(The set of x coordinates), x<sub>k</sub> <= x<sub>i</sub>.  By construction, the rectangle class defines x<sub>1</sub> such that x<sub>1</sub> = x<sub>k</sub>, as can be seen in the source code:

```
public double getMinX() 
{
    return getX();
}

public double getX()
{
    return x;
}
```

and further explained in the constructor:

> Rectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height)
>      Constructs a new Rectangle whose upper-left corner is specified as (x,y) and whose 
>      width and height are specified by the arguments of the same name.

```
 public Rectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height) 
 {
     this.x = x;
     this.y = y;
     this.width = width;
     this.height = height;
 }
```

NB: The other constructors call the above one.

Comment: Thank you a lot, that explanation sums it up very well.

Answer (score 2):

You are right. With a `Rectangle` class, `getMinX()` is the same thing as `getX()`.

When you look at [the source code for OpenJDK's `Rectangle`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/awt/geom/RectangularShape.java#RectangularShape.getMinX%28%29), you can see this:

```
public double getMinX() {
    return getX();
}
```

To be honest, I haven't found a override for this method in the OpenJDK. Maybe I was looking at thw wrong places, I'm not sure. But all the shapes (ellipse, arc etc.) use this implementation. Peculiar.

Right now, I *think* the only difference is the name and the recommended usage. They both do the same thing, but I'd use one or the other in different situations:

- `getX()` when I need the location of the shape, a point
- `getMinX()` when I need the left bound of the shape

Comment: I agree.  From what I can tell, they're basically aliases for each other, and both exist for the sake of clarity/readability.